# Real time scenario for a custom entity provider

Tags: java, jax-rs

In JAX-RS there is an option to define a custom entity provider(message body workers or message body readers and writers) so that you can map a java bean to MIME type (say application/myBean).

Are there any scenario where one would need it?

Comment: isn't this a question? Though the answer changes based on opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason for defining custom Media Types is defining tighter contracts. For instance using the header `Accept: application/vnd.com.example.customer+xml` defines on protocol-level that a list of orders won't be accepted. This is not possible with using `application/xml`.

If you want to use custom Media Types you need custom providers for serialization.

There is a [long going debate](http://www.subbu.org/blog/2009/12/media-types-and-plumbing) if this is a good idea or not.